# Transpose data by groups in R

Tags: r, reshape, data-manipulation

I have data in the following structure:

```
x <- read.table(header=T, text="
X Y D S
a e 1 10
a e 2 20
a f 1 50
b c 1 40
b c 2 30
b c 3 60
b d 1 10 
b d 2 20")
```

And I want to get the following result:

```
X Y   1   2   3
a e  10  20
a f  50
b c  40  30  60
b d  10  20
```

For every combination of columns `X` and `Y` I would like to transpose data in column `S` by order in column `D`.

I thought `xtabs()` will work, but I don't think so, my best version is:

```
xtabs(formula=S~Y+D,data=x)
```

With result:

```
   D
Y    1  2  3
  c 40 30 60
  d 10 20  0
  e 10 20  0
  f 50  0  0
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
require(reshape2)
dcast(x, X + Y ~ D, value.var="S")
```

If you want to fill empty entries with `0` instead of `NA` (which is the default), then,

```
dcast(x, X + Y ~ D, value.var="S", fill=0)
```

Answer (score 9):

A solution in base R:

```
> reshape(x, timevar="D", idvar=c("X","Y"), direction="wide")
  X Y S.1 S.2 S.3
1 a e  10  20  NA
3 a f  50  NA  NA
4 b c  40  30  60
7 b d  10  20  NA
```

Answer (score 4):

The other two answers are very good, but for what it's worth, since you mentioned you started your attempts with `xtabs`, you ***can*** get close to what you were looking for with a combination of `xtabs` and `ftable`. However, the result will include all factor levels

```
ftable(xtabs(S ~ ., x))
#     D  1  2  3
# X Y           
# a c    0  0  0
#   d    0  0  0
#   e   10 20  0
#   f   50  0  0
# b c   40 30 60
#   d   10 20  0
#   e    0  0  0
#   f    0  0  0
```

Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```
data.frame(unique(x[1:2]), 
           as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(S ~ do.call(paste, x[1:2]) + D, x)))
#   X Y X1 X2 X3
# 1 a e 10 20  0
# 3 a f 50  0  0
# 4 b c 40 30 60
# 7 b d 10 20  0
```